# Is there any way of getting deployment results in aws opsworks proactively

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-opsworks

Aws-sdk provides api using which we can deploy and get deployment status, but to get the results one has to keep on querying for results, but is there any way getting status automatically when a deployment is completed. 
i.e., instead of me querying for results, is there any method which returns the status once a deployment is completed. We need this as we are developing a app for automating deployments, once a step gets completed , we can trigger next one.

Comment: I think you want something like 'deployment.waitForCompleted()'. However, there is no such high level API for opsworks SDK. You probably could create some helper methods such as "watiForCompleted".